# What am I missing in my html to make the javascript work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What am I missing here to get my JS slider to work? I have referenced the js files 'js' folder that is within my website folder. I'm using one of the js scripts from http://materializecss.com/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
  </script>

  <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
      <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
      <h2>First Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
      <h2>Second Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
      <h2>Third Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
      <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to put the first script after the script that loads jQuery.

Comment: Load the scripts in the <head>

Comment: you miss JQuery library   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If your code produces console errors you should tell us what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the re organization of the scripts dont forget to call the last script function, that who runs the carousel, with the right name of the class that have the list of images or text(because you are calling in your example a div class "carousel" and there is not a div class with that name
In my case i put "carousel-slider" to both, the div class and the call of the script
this will be an example using only text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>
<body>

   <div class="carousel-slider" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
      <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
      <h2>First Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
      <h2>Second Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
      <h2>Third Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
      <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-slider').carousel();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should include your jQuery library before using it, so :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Should appear before :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

In your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

   BODY CONTENT ....

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `$(document).ready()` until after you've loaded the jQuery library. So put your script at the end, not the beginning.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
      <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
      <h2>First Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
      <h2>Second Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
      <h2>Third Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
      <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```